# Why still not coloring the pixels in acolor using LockBits?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm doing a loop over a List pointtocolor contain over 50000 pixels coordinates then i'm trying to color them on the Bitmap bmpBackClouds.

First time i tried with the line:

```
if ((int)p + (int)(x + y) < bD.Stride * bD.Height)
```

But then it never step in and never did the `p[1] = p[2] = (byte)255;` lines.
So now i'm not using this IF and it's doing all the lines.
But in the end i'm getting the same Bitmap as original as it was nothing colored.

```
float x, y;
bD = bmpBackClouds.LockBits(
    new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmpBackClouds.Width, bmpBackClouds.Height),
    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
IntPtr s0 = bD.Scan0;

unsafe
{
    byte* p;
    byte* pBU = (byte*)(void*)s0;

    for (int i = 0; i < pointtocolor.Count; i++)
    {
        p = (byte*)(void*)s0;
        x = pointtocolor[i].X * (float)currentFactor;
        y = pointtocolor[i].Y * (float)currentFactor;
        if ((int)x >= bmpBackClouds.Width || (int)y >= bmpBackClouds.Height)
        {
            continue;
        }
        x = (int)(y * (float)bD.Stride);
        y = (int)(x * 4F);
        p += (int)(x + y);
        if ((int)p + (int)(x + y) < bD.Stride * bD.Height)
        {
            if (x + y > 3)
                p -= (p - pBU) % 4;
            p[1] = p[2] = (byte)255;
            p[0] = (byte)0;
            p[3] = (byte)255;
        } 
    }
}
bmpBackClouds.UnlockBits(bD);
```

This is the unsafe code part:

unsafe
                    {
                        byte* p;
                        byte* pBU = (byte*)(void*)s0;

```
                    for (int i = 0; i < pointtocolor.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //set pointer to the beggining 
                        p = (byte*)(void*)s0;
                        x = pointtocolor[i].X * (float)currentFactor;
                        y = pointtocolor[i].Y * (float)currentFactor;
                        //check if point is inside bmp 
                        if ((int)x >= bmpBackClouds.Width || (int)y >= bmpBackClouds.Height)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        //Add offset where the point is. The formula: position = Y * stride + X * 4 
                        x = (int)(y * (float)bD.Stride);
                        y = (int)(x * 4F);

                        p += (int)(x + y);
                        //here check, whether the pointer's at a correct position
                        if (x + y > 3)
                            p -= (p - pBU) % 4;

                        //set yellow color 
                        p[1] = p[2] = (byte)255;
                        p[0] = (byte)0;
                        p[3] = (byte)255;
                    }
                }
```

Hans solution is working i just have a small quation the image i get on the hard disk is colored on the right shape but it's opposite or reversed not sure how to call to it what it should be:

[image: opposite]

On the screenshot on the left is whaht i got on the har disk the bitmap i wrote to with the LockBits.
On the right it's my program and a rectangle i drawed in red and this rectangle should be the colored area on the Bitmap. But on the Bitmap i see this rectangle are but it seems like opposite or reversed.

The question is if there is something wrong with the LockBits code ? Or it seems more like something with my other code ?

Comment: I guess the `if ((int)p + (int)(x + y) < bD.Stride * bD.Height)` is not doing what you want it to do - `p` is a address and `bD.Stride*bd.Height` is a size - in most cases, the address will be way bigger. I'm not sure what you try to prevent with that line, could you add some commentary what each line should do from your point of view? I also see some data dependency problems, e.g. you assign `y` to `x` and then `x` to `y`, which makes both dependent on `x`. I guess you want to do a swap there?

Comment: Oliver i added it with some descripations for the lines. In general i want to color the pixels in pointtocolor in Yellow.

Comment: The Bitmap stores the lower rows first, I guess you'll have to invert the Y coordinate: `bitmapY = height - y - 1`
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407212(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

*(p - pBU) % 4* produces always zero. The difference is always multiple of 4 because each pixel has 4bytes of information. The p pointer jumbs to multiple of 4 from the beginning where pBU points. If you want to test if the points are in the rectangle do this:

```
GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
gp.AddRectangle(new RectangleF(?, ?, ?, ?)); //fill the values of your rectangle

for (int i = 0; i < pointtocolor.Count; i++)
{
    if(gp.IsVisible (pointtocolor[i].X * (float)currentFactor, pointtocolor[i].Y * (float)currentFactor) 
    {
        //is inside
    }
}
```

EDIT

When scanning a bitmap and use *bD.Stride* to see the width using an *int* pointer is wrong because stride gives *color byte count* not *pixel count*

```
int *p;
p = (int*)(void*)s0;
//x, y the position coordinates
p += y * bD.Stride + x * 4; //wrong

byte *p;
p = (byte*)(void*)s0;
//x, y the position coordinates
p += y * bD.Stride + x * 4; //correct
```

The error is here

```
x = (int)(y * (float)bD.Stride);
y = (int)(x * 4F);
```

You are using previous x to set y!

The correct code is:

```
float fx, fy;
int x, y;
bD = bmpBackClouds.LockBits(
new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmpBackClouds.Width, bmpBackClouds.Height),
System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
IntPtr s0 = bD.Scan0;

unsafe
{
    byte* p;
    //byte* pBU = (byte*)(void*)s0;

    for (int i = 0; i < pointtocolor.Count; i++)
    {
        p = (byte*)(void*)s0;
        fx = pointtocolor[i].X * (float)currentFactor;
        fy = pointtocolor[i].Y * (float)currentFactor;
        if ((int)fx >= bmpBackClouds.Width || (int)fy >= bmpBackClouds.Height)
        {
            continue;
        }
        x = (int)fy * bD.Stride;
        y = (int)fx * 4;
        p += (x + y);

        p[1] = p[2] = (byte)255;
        p[0] = (byte)0;
        p[3] = (byte)255;
    }
}
bmpBackClouds.UnlockBits(bD);
```

valter

Comment: Do you care downvoter to explain the reason? Not to mention that it is working